# quick sort error using C++

Tags: c++, quicksort

This program is giving me the error message. I does not know what is causing this error, would you help me?

```
error C2109: "subscript requires array or pointer type "
```

Here is the code

```
void quicksort(int input,int left,int right)
{ 
int i=left,j=right; // initailizing left and right limit 

int pivot = input[(i+j)/2];

while (i<=j)
{
    while (input[i]<pivot)
    { i++; }


    while (input[j]>pivot) // if right side limit is greater than pivot, >p will move to left
    { j--; }

    if (i<=j) // when left limit less than right limit swap value
    {
        swap(input[i],input[j]);

        i++;
        j--;
    } // end if 
} // end of while

if (left<j)
    quicksort(input,left,j);

if (i<right)
    quicksort(input,i,right);
    }




int main () {
    int input[10]={3,7,2,1,99,10,15,74,11,31};

}
quicksort(input,left,right); //calling function in main

cout<<"the sorted numbers are:\n"; // showing sorted array

for(int a=o;a<10;a++)
{
    cout<<setw (4)<<input[a]<<endl;
}
system ("pause");
```

}

Comment: Why didn't you tell us which line has the error? We are not psychic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `input` as an array while it's an `int`. You probably have forgotten to put `[]`:

```
void quicksort(int input[],int left,int right)
                        ^^
```

Also, you have some typos such as `o` instead of `0`, a redundant `}` and ...

[***Here is a live working code***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2a67f6ceaaff686)

Comment: THANKS ALOT SIR major mistake of mine :)'may god bless u

Comment: only 1 more question plzzzz "how can i know no of comparisions and swaps made in my quicksort array plz help plz

Comment: Simplest way is to put flags. Another way is to check if the array was sorted before or not.

Answer (score 2):

`input` is declared as an integer but you try to access to `input[(i+j)/2]`

Answer (score 1):

Input should be a pointer to the head of the input array, your function header should either declare it a pointer or an array.

```
void quicksort(int* input,int left,int right)
```